# Вывод результатов цикла for в переменную

Tags: bash, sh

Не могу разобраться как вынести в одну переменную обработанный перебор цикла for в shell. Код такой:

```
#!/bin/sh
SRCS=module1 module2
MODULES=`for SRC in $(SRCS); do echo "src/$$SRC.bin" ; done`
echo $$MODULES
```

Должно вывести

```
src/module1.bin src/module2.bin
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, правильный синтаксис.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh
SRCS="module1 module2"
MODULES=$(for SRC in $SRCS; do echo "src/$SRC.bin" ; done)
echo $MODULES
```

- строки надо заключать в кавычки
- программы, команды или функции по имени `SRCS` в системе, скорее всего, нет, потому исполнять её вряд ли имеет смысл (`$(SRCS)`)
- подстановка значения переменной — `$имя` или `${имя}`. а `$$` — это переменная, содержащая номер процесса

Comment: Спасибо, сработало)

Answer (score 0):

Используем bash arrays и sed, если уж взялись за bash :-)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

SRCS=(module1 module2)
MODULES=""

# Просто вывод
for src in ${SRCS[@]}; do
    printf "src/%s.bin " "${src}"
done
echo

# обновление переменной
for src in ${SRCS[@]}; do
    MODULES+=" src/${src}.bin"
done
echo "${MODULES}"

# Hacker's way
SRCS="module1 module2"
MODULES="$(echo $SRCS | sed 's/\</src\//g' | sed 's/\>/\.bin/g')"
echo "${MODULES}"

~$ ./script.sh
src/module1.bin src/module2.bin 
 src/module1.bin src/module2.bin
src.bin/module1.bin src.bin/module2.bin
```

echo лючше не использовать для подстановок, есть более гибкий printf

- http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arrays
- https://github.com/Hellseher/cix/blob/master/spices/cix-sed.org